# Check return value of get_posts

Tags: wp-query, query, get-posts

I've been trying to change my `WP_Query` to `get_posts` methods. But I am not really sure how to check if `get_posts` is null or have a value.

How can i transform this `WP_Query` checker to appropriate `get_posts` checker?

This is my `WP_Query` checker:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From previous questions, I know you would want optimize your queries. There is no need to change `WP_Query` into `get_posts` for perfomance. As I stated in a another post, yes, `get_posts()` is faster than `WP_Query` because `get_posts()` legally breaks pagination, but what `get_posts()` do can be done with `WP_Query`.

To really understand what `get_posts()` does, lets look at the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). In essence, `get_posts()` does the following: (*lets forget about the useless parameters in `get_posts()`*)

```
$args = [
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    // Any other user passed arguments
];
$r = new WP_Query( $args );
return $r->posts;
```

### WHAT DOES IT ALL MEAN

- `get_posts()` just returns the `$posts` property from the query object. `$posts` holds an array of posts
- `'no_found_rows' => true` is what legally breaks pagination, and is one of the reasons why you should not use `get_posts` for paginated queries. This is also why `get_posts()` is faster than a normal `WP_Query` as by default `no_found_rows` is set to false.

Because `get_posts()` only returns an array of posts, and not the query object, you must use a normal `foreach` loop to loop through the posts. Another thing to note, because the query object is not returned, the template tags like `the_content()` is not available because the `$post` global is not set to the current post. In a normal loop, `the_post()` sets up postdata which makes template tags available. For `get_posts()`, we need to do this manually by using `setup_postdata( $post )` in our foreach loop

To properly loop through `get_posts()`, we need to do something like this

```
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
if ( $posts_array ) { // Make sure we have posts before we attempt to loop through them
    foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // Now we can use template tags
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
}
```

I would not go through all of this to change existing `WP_Query` instances in order to optimize them. Simply add `'no_found_rows' => true` to your `WP_Query` arguments, and viola, you are doing exatly what `get_posts()` is doing

Comment: Wow you are really amazing me with your answers, @pieter. So basically, it's okay to not convert my wp_query by using no_found_rows to true, right? i've been transforming my query from query_posts to wp_query to get_posts.

Comment: Correct, `no_found_rows` is all that is needed. You do not need to convert `WP_Query` to `get_posts`. Note again, make sure you do not need pagination in the query

Comment: Yes. I am not needing pagination in all my queries. Thank you so much, @pieter.

Comment: My pleasure. You should download and install the query monitor plugin on your local test install. This will tell you how many queries you are doing per page and how long it takes to run that queries ;-)

Comment: thank you. You've been a great help, ever since i started asking question here. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple `empty` function.

```
$wpse_posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( ! empty( $wpse_posts ) ) {
    //Do the loop

} else {
   //No post found
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @sumit, :). I gratefully appreciate your answer.

Comment: Do not use `$posts` as a local variable, it is a reserved global variable. You are breaking that variable which causes other big issues

Comment: @Sumit The `$post` **AND** `$posts` globals are set [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/register_globals/), note the plural `s` in `$posts`

Comment: @PieterGoosen I do not expect this downvote from you. What do you see when you print `$posts` in a template ? It is `NULL`, you first need to globalize the variable with `global $variable;`

Comment: @Sumit `$posts` **is** a global variable, I just proved that to you. This is very basic PHP. `$posts === $GLOBALS['posts']`. I'm not going argue about this, as I said, I have already proven my point from WordPress core source code

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've accepted the truth. I definitely not arguing with you. I am just saying downvote is not good when question does not say that I am in main loop. `function myposts() {
    return $posts;
}
print_r(myposts());` and `print_r($posts)` have difference.  You assumed the code directly in template. I assumed it in `functions.php` within in a function